# Bootstrap - Vue Tabs: Force tab-content to fill remaining height of parent

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a tabs component (`b-tabs`) in my page. The component is wrapped inside a parent div with specific height.

I want the tabs's content to get full remaining height of parent component.

[image]

This is a basic skeleton of my tabs, nothing fancy:

```
<div class="h-100">
    <b-tabs content-class="mt-3 h-100">
        <b-tab title="First" active>
            <div class="tab-content">I'm the first tab</div>
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab title="Second">
            <div class="tab-content">I'm the second tab</div>
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab title="Third">
            <div class="tab-content">I'm the third tab!</div>
        </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
</div>
```

After inspecting the DOM, I have tried setting `height: 100%` to the following classes:

```
.tabs, .tab-pane, .tab-content, .my-tab-content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This produces an overflow of content cause it is sibling to the tabs bar (thus, it gets 100% of parent container and the overflow equals the height of the tabs bar).

I have thought of calculating the height of the tabs bar and set the height of content using `height: calc(100% - **px)` but I suppose there could be a more elegant solution.

***Check codesandbox:*** https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-thunder-nwmzu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `display: flex` on the tabs, and then using the `flex-grow-1` [utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink), which will fill out all remaining space inside the flex container.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.tabs-container {
  height: 400px;
  background: #d8d8d8;
}

.tab-pane {
  height: 100%;
}

.my-tab-content {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: rgba(80, 10, 10, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <div class="tabs-container">
    <b-tabs class="h-100 d-flex flex-column" content-class="mt-3 flex-grow-1">
      <b-tab title="First" active>
        <div class="my-tab-content">
          See at the bottom: The content of tabs overflows container
        </div>
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Second">
        <div class="my-tab-content">I'm the second tab</div>
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Third">
        <div class="my-tab-content">I'm the third tab!</div>
      </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </div>
</div>
```